# How can I disable TLSv1 without change source code?

Tags: java, ssl

I write a test code(not HTTPS) to test TLS with JDK8. When the test code runs, I use nmap tool to scan and get result as follow:

```
D:\softwares\nmap-7.12>nmap -p xxxx --script=ssl* x.x.x.x --unprivileged


Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-26 15:33 °?′óà????÷2?±ê×?ê±??
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x
Host is up (1.0s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
xxxx/tcp open unknown
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|  TLSv1.0:
|    ciphers:
|      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) -A
|    compressors:
|      NULL
|    cipher preference: indeterminate
|    cipher preference error: Too few ciphers supported
|  TLSv1.1:
|    ciphers:
|      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) -A
|    compressors:
|      NULL
|    cipher preference: indeterminate
|    cipher preference error: Too few ciphers supported
|  TLSv1.2:
|    ciphers:
|      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) -A
|    compressors:
|      NULL
|    cipher preference: indeterminate
|    cipher preference error: Too few ciphers supported
|_ least strength: A
MAC Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx


Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.88 seconds


D:\softwares\nmap-7.12>
```

JDK8 enables TLSv1.0 as default, but I want to disable it.

```
Protocols
The SunJSSE provider supports the following protocol parameters:
Protocol    Enabled by Default for Client   Enabled by Default for Server
SSLv3       No(Unavailable Footnote 2)      No(Unavailable Footnote 2)
TLSv1       Yes                             Yes
TLSv1.1     Yes                             Yes
TLSv1.2     Yes                             Yes
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSE_Protocols

I invoke "setEnabledProtocols" method of javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine class on my test code, TLSv1.0 can be disabled perfectly.
Is there a way to disable TLSv1.0 without change code? for example via configuration file.
I tried several methods as follow, but no one can achieve the desired effect :(
1. -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
2. -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false

Here is the java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be writing a server, and `jdk.tls.client.protocols` applies to clients, hence the name; although slightly less obvious, in basic JavaSE 'deployment' means browser-or-WebStart which is a subset of client.

There is no property specifically for TLS (or HTTPS) server protocols, but the security property `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` applies to both client and server (and all context types also) and can be set in `JRE/lib/security/java.security` as stated in the page you linked. Be sure to keep the existing restrictions (especially removing SSLv3, since 8u31) while adding yours.

Comment: Caveat emptor, `-D` will *not* work for `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`, as you suggested it should go into `java.security` file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your reply first.
If modify `JRE/lib/security/java.security`, that will have a global impact.

Here is my solution:
Copy `JRE/lib/security/java.security` to a new file, and add TLSv1 to `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`.
then, start JVM like this:
java `-Djava.security.properties=./java.security` -jar xxxxx

Here is the summary from `JRE/lib/security/java.security`:

```
#
# This is the "master security properties file".
#
# An alternate java.security properties file may be specified
# from the command line via the system property
#
#    -Djava.security.properties=<URL>
#
# This properties file appends to the master security properties file.
# If both properties files specify values for the same key, the value
# from the command-line properties file is selected, as it is the last
# one loaded.
#
# Also, if you specify
#
#    -Djava.security.properties==<URL> (2 equals),
#

#
# Determines whether this properties file can be appended to
# or overridden on the command line via -Djava.security.properties
#
security.overridePropertiesFile=true
```