# How do I specify the keystore type on the command line?

Tags: java, keystore

In the java.security file, you can specify the keystore.type value. However, that looks like it changes the default keystore type for all JVM instances. I just want to change it for one instance.

Currently, it is set to "jks", but I need it to be "jceks". I tried `-Djava.security.keystore.type=jceks` but that doesn't seem to do what I want it to do.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Dname=value` sets a system property; **the settings in `java.security` are security properties not system properties**, and cannot be directly set on command line. You *can* create a supplementary (or replacement) *file* and specify that with a sysprop `-Djava.security.properties=name_of_file_containing_keystore_setting` as long as you (or anyone else) did not change the default setting of `security.overridePropertiesFile=true` in `java.security`. Similar: [How can I disable TLSv1 without change source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649939/how-can-i-disable-tlsv1-without-change-source-code) .

Note that if you only need to change the type of the truststore and/or keystore used by **JSSE for SSL/TLS/HTTPS/etc** by default, *those* do use sysprops `javax.net.ssl.{trust,key}StoreType` (along with `{trust,key}Store{,Password}`).

Also you might want to be aware that Java9 up changes the as-installed default to PKCS12, which is both more secure and more portable/interoperable than JKS.

Comment: So, since I'm using the keystore for more than just storing trusted certs, do I need to make sure that the `javax.net.ssl.{trust,key}StoreType` property isn't set?

Comment: If you are using JSSE (SSL/TLS) _defaults_, you need to set the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore*` sysprops if they are different from the default, and the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore*` sysprops if they are used at all (because the default is 'none'). If you use JSSE with nondefault stores or managers, or do something that is not SSL/TLS but uses X.509/PKIX like S/MIME or (some) XMLdsig/enc or code-signing, or do something that is PKC but not X.509/PKIX like PGP or SSH, then the JSSE sysprops are irrelevant.